# Get rid of newline from shell commands in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems

I am trying to run simple shell commands in my script, but am unable to get rid of new lines even using chomp or chop.

Is there something I am missing ?

```
      u=`echo  '#{l}' | cut -d: -f4`.chop()
      p2=`echo '#{l}' | cut -d: -f3`.chop()
      p1=`echo '#{l}' | cut -d: -f2`.chop()
      h=`echo  '#{l}' | cut -d: -f1`.chop()


#     **Cant get newlines to go after p1 and p2 !! ??**
      path="#{p1}/server/#{p2}abc"
      puts path


 Output:
 /usr (p1)
 /server
 /bin (p2) abc 
 Expected Output:
 /usr/server/binabc
```

Any suggestions ?

As per some suggestions, changed my code to :

```
h, p1, p2, u = l.split /:/
u.strip 
u.chomp

puts u.inspect
```

Output: `"string\n"`

Basically I had tried using chomp before and was hitting the same problem. Do I need to call chomp in a different way or add any gem ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use either [`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001189) to remove all wrapping whitespace, or [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188) (note the 'm') to remove a single trailing newline only.

[`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001187) removes the last character (or `\r\n` pair) which could be dangerous if the command does not always end with a newline.

I assume that your code did not work because the results had multiple newlines\whitespace at the end of the output. (And if so, `strip` will work for you.) You can verify this, however, by removing the call to `chop`, and then using `p u` or `puts u.inspect` to see what characters are actually in the output.

*And for your information, it's idiomatic in Ruby to omit parentheses when calling methods that take no arguments, e.g. `u = foo.chop`.*

Comment: Thanx @phrogz . I posted the output of u.inspect . I am still hitting the same issue, am I not invoking it the right way ?

Comment: @codeObserver Using `u.chomp` will not do anything, as this is the non-mutating version of the method. You need to either do `u.chomp!` or `u = u.chomp`. The same goes for `.strip` versus `.strip!`.

Answer (score 5):

[`str.chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188)wll remove the newline character from strings.
`str.chop` only removes the last character.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling out to the shell for something so simple:

```
h, p1, p2, u = l.split /:/
```

Comment: thnx glenn. Basically I am still learning Ruby and trying to port some shell scripts to Ruby. So as a first iteration trying to just run shell commands natively in a ruby structure and then I would take a pass to weed out the un-necessary

Comment: Then `chomp` is what you want.